# check_assumptions via stdin/smt2?

Tags: command, z3, stdio

Does the SMT2 standard (or a Z3 extension of it) offer a command equivalent to the API-call "check_assumptions"? According to [Josh Berdine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7736632/491216) it is often faster to work with guard literals and check_assumptions than with push-pop scopes. However, I am stuck with using Z3 via stdio for now, and using `(check-assumoptions p)` only yields `unsupported`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the smt2 command language, perhaps the 'get-core' command available with 'z3 -smtc -in' will do the job?  Note that I think this command is not in the SMT-LIB 2 standard.

Cheers, Josh

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick! It is indeed not mentioned in the SMT-LIB2 standard, but I currently only target Z3 anyway.

Comment: Quick note: -smtc option enables a deprecated parser (it is not compliant with the SMT 2.0 standard). This front-end will be removed in future versions of Z3. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439556/soft-hard-constraints-in-z3 for unsat cores extraction in the new SMT 2.0 parser.