# Copying Z3 Solver

Tags: z3

I have seen in the post: [Is it possible to clone Z3_context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726607/is-it-possible-to-clone-z3-context) that the ability to copy/clone the solver was planned for addition to Z3, to facilitate some backtracking behaviour. I have looked in the C API documentation and I could not currently find a way to do this.

Is it now possible to copy the solver through the C API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API does not have a method for copying a Solver object, but it can be simulated using `Z3_solver_get_assertions` and `Z3_solver_assert`. The idea is to create a new Solver object, and copy the assertions from the old to the new.